# Got EOF when reading from device only when heating the bed

Tags: klipper

I'm having "Got EOF when reading from device" only while heating the bed. however, if I run PID_calibrate for the heater bed and set the temperature to 50 °C. The PID_calibrate will auto-change to 45 °C and I get no shutdowns.

Another point is when the bed temperature is at 20 °C and I manually change it to 40 °C the bed will use 100% power until the bed reaches the temperature around 35 °C and then keeps fluctuating and changing the power from 10% to 40% to 97% to 60%.

Things I have tried that haven't fixed the problem:

- Changed the connection cable between the Raspberry Pi and the MCU and changed the cable to power up the Raspberry Pi.
- Changed the power supply for the Raspberry Pi.
- Removed the camera from the Raspberry Pi.
- Changed the board to Raspberry Pi 4 with a stronger power supply, and kept trying different USB sockets to no avail.
- I did a clean re-flash and re-install of everything (Klipper and firmware).
- Checked the MCU cable that they are connected properly.

Printer: Kobra Max
Upgrades: R65 to R65 Jumper
Board: Pi Zero 2 W

Recently when I was checking the Klippy.log I would see NULL lines in the log.

Klippy.log output:

```
Starting heater checks for extruder
Stats 29.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000000 mcu_task_stddev=0.000000 bytes_write=1997 bytes_read=4261 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=166 receive_seq=166 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.002 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993922  heater_bed: target=0 temp=0.0 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.29 cputime=1.048 memavail=3659392 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=0.0 pwm=0.000
webhooks client 4131026064: New connection webhooks client 4131026064: Client info {'program': 'Moonraker', 'version': 'v0.8.0-182-g9785387'} webhooks: registering remote method 'shutdown_machine' for connection id: 4131026064 webhooks: registering remote method 'reboot_machine' for connection id: 4131026064 webhooks: registering remote method 'pause_job_queue' for connection id: 4131026064 webhooks: registering remote method 'start_job_queue' for connection id: 4131026064 
Stats 30.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000000 mcu_task_stddev=0.000000 bytes_write=2003 bytes_read=4307 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=167 receive_seq=167 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199992990  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.27 cputime=1.061 memavail=3659792 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 31.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.003 mcu_task_avg=0.000010 mcu_task_stddev=0.000019 bytes_write=2009 bytes_read=4443 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=168 receive_seq=168 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199992513  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.27 cputime=1.078 memavail=3659672 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 32.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.003 mcu_task_avg=0.000010 mcu_task_stddev=0.000019 bytes_write=2015 bytes_read=4564 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=169 receive_seq=169 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199994131  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.27 cputime=1.095 memavail=3659672 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 33.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.003 mcu_task_avg=0.000010 mcu_task_stddev=0.000019 bytes_write=2021 bytes_read=4670 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=170 receive_seq=170 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993743  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.27 cputime=1.105 memavail=3659076 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 34.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.003 mcu_task_avg=0.000010 mcu_task_stddev=0.000019 bytes_write=2027 bytes_read=4783 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=171 receive_seq=171 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993249  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.27 cputime=1.113 memavail=3655044 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 35.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.003 mcu_task_avg=0.000010 mcu_task_stddev=0.000019 bytes_write=2033 bytes_read=4901 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=172 receive_seq=172 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993184  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.25 cputime=1.122 memavail=3653168 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 36.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2039 bytes_read=5020 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=173 receive_seq=173 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993078  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.25 cputime=1.128 memavail=3653168 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 37.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2045 bytes_read=5141 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=174 receive_seq=174 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199992990  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.1 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.25 cputime=1.135 memavail=3653168 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 38.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2051 bytes_read=5262 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=175 receive_seq=175 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199992945  heater_bed: target=0 temp=33.2 pwm=0.000 sysload=0.25 cputime=1.147 memavail=3652468 print_time=0.001 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000
Heater heater_bed approaching new target of 40.000 
Stats 39.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2073 bytes_read=5373 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=177 receive_seq=177 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993184  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.1 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.25 cputime=1.167 memavail=3652468 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.7 pwm=0.000 
Stats 40.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2095 bytes_read=5499 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=179 receive_seq=179 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993465  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.1 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.31 cputime=1.182 memavail=3649696 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 41.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2101 bytes_read=5633 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=180 receive_seq=180 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993376  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.2 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.31 cputime=1.191 memavail=3652476 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.5 pwm=0.000 
Stats 42.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2107 bytes_read=5739 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=181 receive_seq=181 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993289  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.2 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.31 cputime=1.197 memavail=3652476 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 43.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2129 bytes_read=5865 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=183 receive_seq=183 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993252  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.3 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.31 cputime=1.204 memavail=3652476 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 44.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2135 bytes_read=5986 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=184 receive_seq=184 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993197  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.4 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.31 cputime=1.211 memavail=3652476 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 45.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2141 bytes_read=6092 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=185 receive_seq=185 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993219  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.4 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.28 cputime=1.220 memavail=3652480 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 46.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2179 bytes_read=6236 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=188 receive_seq=188 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993307  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.6 pwm=0.846 sysload=0.28 cputime=1.236 memavail=3649572 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.7 pwm=0.000 
Stats 47.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2233 bytes_read=6372 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=192 receive_seq=192 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993302  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.5 pwm=1.000 sysload=0.28 cputime=1.246 memavail=3652492 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 48.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2282 bytes_read=6488 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=195 receive_seq=195 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993262  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.7 pwm=0.784 sysload=0.28 cputime=1.253 memavail=3652492 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000
b'Got EOF when reading from device' 
Stats 49.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2320 bytes_read=6574 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=198 receive_seq=198 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=0 freq=199993201  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.8 pwm=0.875 sysload=0.28 cputime=1.261 memavail=3652492 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 50.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2320 bytes_read=6574 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=198 receive_seq=198 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=1 freq=199993201  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.8 pwm=0.875 sysload=0.26 cputime=1.266 memavail=3652492 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 51.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2320 bytes_read=6574 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=198 receive_seq=198 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=2 freq=199993201  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.8 pwm=0.875 sysload=0.26 cputime=1.273 memavail=3652492 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 52.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2320 bytes_read=6574 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=198 receive_seq=198 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=3 freq=199993201  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.8 pwm=0.875 sysload=0.26 cputime=1.283 memavail=3651152 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000 
Stats 53.2: gcodein=0  mcu: mcu_awake=0.000 mcu_task_avg=0.000005 mcu_task_stddev=0.000004 bytes_write=2320 bytes_read=6574 bytes_retransmit=0 bytes_invalid=0 send_seq=198 receive_seq=198 retransmit_seq=0 srtt=0.003 rttvar=0.000 rto=0.025 ready_bytes=0 upcoming_bytes=4 freq=199993201  heater_bed: target=40 temp=33.8 pwm=0.875 sysload=0.26 cputime=1.290 memavail=3653008 print_time=47.779 buffer_time=0.000 print_stall=0 extruder: target=0 temp=24.6 pwm=0.000
�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```